# addEventListener и Promise

Tags: javascript

Ситуация следующая. Есть какой-то класс `A`, при создании которого в конструкторе на определенный узел DOM должен быть навешен обработчик. При срабатывании события, зарегистрированного этим обработчиком должно вывестись сообщение и вызваться метод `_handleCall()`.

Я решил попробовать реализовать при помощи Promise'ов:

```
class A {
    constructor() {
        this._waitForCall().then(_handleCall);
    }

    _waitForCall() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let handler = (event) => {
                console.log("called.");
                resolve(event);
            };

            this.target.addEventListener("click", handler);
        });
    }

    _handleCall(event) {
        console.log(event);
    }
}
```

Однако я заметил, что при таком подходе метод `_handleCall` вызывается только один раз, хотя сообщение "called." из обработчика `handler` выводится при каждом клике на элементе.

Насколько я понимаю, так происходит потому, что у каждого Promise'а есть некое состояние, которое может измениться только единожды. И после его изменения в "fulfilled" (которое происходит после первого нажатия по элементу), метод `then` на Promise'е уже больше никогда вызван не будет. И отсюда **первый вопрос**: правильно ли я это понимаю?

В общем, я решил, что ситуацию можно исправив, добавив в `_handleCall` повторную регистрацию Promise'а:

```
_handleCall(event) {
    console.log(event);
    this._waitForCall().then((e) => this._handleCall(e));
}
```

Однако здесь ситуация тоже неоднозначно. Прежде всего плохо то, что при таком подходе на элементе `this.target` обработчик один и тот же будет регистрироваться `n`-ое количество раз, что ни есть хорошо. И, хотя эта проблема довольно легко решается, мне все равно кажется, что такой подход - ужасный костыль. Правильно ли я понимаю (и это **второй вопрос**), что Promise'ы для того и нужны, чтобы обрабатывать какой-то асинхронный код *единожды*?

Ну и здесь же возникает **третий вопрос**: а стоит ли вообще работать с событиями и их обработчиками при помощи Promise'ов? Я изначально решил, что стоит, потому что события, они, вроде как, асинхронные. А сейчас принято с любым асинхронным кодом работать при помощи Promise'ов. Но ведь с другой стороны обработчики навешиваются по той же причине. И я с таким же успехом мог бы реализовать все примерно так:

```
class A {
    constructor() {
        this._registerCallEventListener(); // просто вызываем метод, навешивающий обработчик
    }

    _registerCallEventListener() {
        let handler = (event) => {
            console.log("called.");
            this._handleCall(event); // вызываем напрямую
        };

        this.target.addEventListener("click", handler);
    }

    _handleCall(event) {
        console.log(event);
    }
}
```

В общем, как лучше поступить?

Comment: Да, промис дохнет после режекта или резольва, и затем уже тыкать палкой его бесполезно. Лучше использовать либо коллбэки, либо промисы, ибо это просто разная реализация одних и тех же целей (выполнить кусок кода после асинхронного действия). Главным плюсом у промисов можно выделить возможность ожидать результата сразу нескольких асинхронных действий и только затем выполнить коллбэк (https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), незаменимо при сборках чего-либо из разных источников.